# Detect navigation buttons bar appearance in WP8 Silverlight app on Lumia 730/735

Tags: silverlight, button, windows-phone-8, navigation, lumia

Lumia 730/735 have the on-screen navigation buttons, and this bar can be hidden/displayed using the swipe upward screen gesture. System apps correctly process the moment when this bar is hidden or displayed - they increase/decrease the height of their current page accordingly.

I have been developing a WP8 Silverlight app to manage checklists for 2 years. Recently I've obtained a Lumia 730 phone, and I'm testing my app on it. As I can see, some pages of my app does not fit the available screen size automatically. Look, for instance, at the following picture - I can't scroll a checklist to see the very last item when the navigation buttons bar becomes visible (the right screen):

[image: WP8 checklist app with on-screen navigation buttons bar]

As I understand, this happens because of some settings and non-standard page layout I use. My question is the following: how can I detect the moment when the visibility of the on-screen navigation buttons bar changes to correct the layout of my page from code?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, as far as i know, you cannot get any information about the bottom on-screen navigation status bar in Windows Phone 8. This is a good reason to develop a Windows Universal application. Propably this is what Microsoft wants from the developers.